# inapproximability of logarithic factor of indepence set

Tags: approximation-algorithms, approximation-hardness

The hardness result derived using PCP theorem for Independent set suggests that there exists some absolute constant $\epsilon_0$ such that for $0< \epsilon < \epsilon_0$, it is hard to approximate independence number $\alpha$ with a factor $n^{1-\epsilon}$.

What does this tell about some quantity (say $p$) that has a one to one correspondence with say $\ln \alpha$. Is the same inapproximation ratio preserved for $p$ or the inapproximation ratio also becomes logarithmic?

Thanks in advance.